# Edit parent object's attributes in a nested object

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to solve a problem where I have a class which is used to store objects of other classes. I want to be able to create a list in that parent object of certain types of nested objects. (sorry if I'm phrasing this badly)

For my example I am taking a real world problem of a House. In the house we may have many different 'things'. We could have people, pets, furniture, computers etc.

I want to be able to store this in a nested format so I create a House with any of those sub-objects within.

E.g

```
old_rectory = House(
    Person('Barry'),
    Person('Bob'),
    Pet('Bill'),
    Pet('Brenda')
)
```

I have created 3 classes: the first is for the House itself, then I have a class for people and a class for pets.

For the `house` class I use *argv so that I can add as many other objects as necessary.

Now in the example above I would like to be able to access `old_rectory.people` and see a list of any instances in `old_rectory` that are of the type `Person`.

```
class House:

    def __init__(self,*argv):
        self.people = []
        self.pets = []
        for arg in argv:
            if isinstance(arg, Person):
                self.people.append(arg)
            elif isinstance(arg, Pet):
                self.pets.append(arg)

class Person:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class Pet:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
```

You can see that I have achieved this by hard coding the lists and some if conditions into the `House` class. But this means that whenever I create a new class I also need to add in a new list and the logic to the `House` class.

I would like to be able to access the `house` object's attributes from the individual classes (`Person`, `Pet`, etc.) but I am unsure of how to proceed or if it is even possible.

```
class Doors:

    NOW CREATE THE NEW LIST IN HOUSE CLASS

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        NOW APPEND THIS OBJECT TO THE NEW LIST IN THE HOUSE CLASS
```

Comment: Please add expected output and obtained output for clarity.

Comment: Simply the fact that you're separating your lists inside `House` necessitates that you hardcode those lists and logic every time you add a new class, or that you dynamically create lists in some way or another. Whether you do that from within `Doors` or not is somewhat irrelevant, and in fact it's probably less problematic to add this kind of logic to `House` than to the other classes. How about you don't do any of that though, and you store it all inside a single list, and you dynamically filter that list *upon access*? `o_r.get_all(Pet)` for example. Even `o_r[Pet]` is possible.

Comment: I don't think you can be able to access the house object's attributes from the individual classes (Person, Pet, etc.) but I am unsure of how to proceed or if it is even possible.

Comment: Can the `Decorator Pattern` be used to achieve what he wants? I was reading about it lately but I haven't tried it yet so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two clear patterns on how to try to overcome this:

#### Create methods for getting the instances of a specific class

Simply put every instance inside a big list and add methods to get each "sublist":

```
class House:
    def __init__(self,*argv): 
        self.things = [*argv] 

    @property
    def pets(self):
        return [thing for thing in self.things if isinstance(thing, Pet)]

    @property
    def people(self):
        return [thing for thing in self.things if isinstance(thing, Person)]
```

This doesn't really solve your initial problem, but at least it's easier and cleaner to implement for new classes - if a list attribute does not exist, it's because you haven't implemented the method for it.

#### Use `hasattr`, `setattr` and `getattr`

Use these functions on the `__init__` method to programatically check if each list exists, create them if needed and append each instance to the corresponding list:

```
class House:
    def __init__(self,*argv): 
        for arg in argv:
            name = arg.__class__.__name__.lower()
            if not hasattr(self, name):
                setattr(self, name, [])
            getattr(self, name).append(arg)
```

I personally think this is worse, since your attributes will be named exactly like the class name (i.e. `person`, not `people`), and you can't clearly see which lists are initialized as attributes or not since it's done on the fly, but it should work for your described use case.

Whichever way you decide to go with, note that I personally feel like your design isn't very effective for dealing with this problem. I'd rather create empty lists for `people`, `pets` etc on the `House`'s `__init__` method and add specific methods like `add_person`, `add_pet`, `add_group` etc for appending objects to the `House`'s list attributes. It may not seem like much, but this design:

- **a)** clearly defines supported classes that can interact with the `House` class; and
- **b)** lets you see more clearly exactly who is getting put into the `House`, since you need to explicitly call the method in order to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I have restructured your code. Check it out :)

```
class House:

    def __init__(self,*argv):
        self.house_classes = {"people": Person, "pets": Pet}
        self.house_objects = {}

        for object in argv:
            self.add_house_object(object)

    def add_house_class(self, class_id, class):
        self.house_classes["class_id"] = class

    def add_house_object(self, object):
        for class_id in self.house_classes:
            if isinstance(object, self.house_classes[class_id]):
                if class_id in self.house_objects:
                    self.house_objects["class_name"].append(object)
                    return
                self.house_objects["class_id"] = [object]

    class Person:
        def __init__(self,name):
            self.name = name

    class Pet:
        def __init__(self,name):
            self.name = name
```

To add new classes (e.g Doors) to a house object (as i think you want)

```
my_house = House(house_objects...) #initialise a house object

class Doors: #your new class to add to house object
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

my_house.add_house_class(self, "doors", Doors) #added to house object

new_door = Door("my door") #door object

my_house.add_house_object(new_door)
```

I hope that helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You can check if `House` has a `doors` list with `getattr(House, 'doors', None)` and create the list if it is not existing. This solution assumes **that you intend to create the list as a class variable** (I am assuming this, since you do NOT pass any `House`-instance reference do `Doors` when instantiating a `Doors` instance).

```
class Doors:
    def __init__(self,name):
        if getattr(House, 'doors', None) is None:    
            House.doors = []

        self.name = name
        House.doors.append(self)
```

**BUT** I strongly advise you to **NOT USE THIS PATTERN**. This looks like a good case for **class inheritance**, for example creating the class `Doors` with `class Doors(House):`.
Furthermore I've got the feeling that you should take a look at the definitions and meanings of **class variables** and **instance variables**.

Imho the best way to deal with this task would be to make `Doors` a class which inherits from `House` and to require an existing instance of house to be able to create a `Doors` instance (for example check with `if isinstance(new_house, House):`). Then the Doors `__init__` method could create and/or append a list `doors` as **instance variable** to `House`.

This way you can create many different houses. Whereas when using a **class variable** for the `doors` list, **each house would have all doors created in all houses**.

Thus I recommend using this pattern:

```
class Doors(House):
    def __init__(self, name, house):
        if not isinstance(house, House):
            raise ValueError('`house` is not an existing instance of the `House` class')
        if getattr(house, 'doors', None) is None:    
            house.doors = []
        else:
            print('exi')
        self.name = name
        house.doors.append(self)
```

As jfaccioni pointed out: Inheritance is not mandatory here, but this kind of construct looks like you are going to need it in the long term for method-access etc.

Comment: imo OP's design problem has to do with composition, not inheritance. `Door` is not a type of `House`, nor does it need to inherit methods from `House` like `has_bathroom` or `number_of_dormitories`.

Comment: This is true in the current way it is composed. No inheritance is needed here. But having a parent class containing lists of child-classes in my experience (in the long term) in almost all cases results in also having a subset of methods in the parent class, which need to be accessible by child-classes.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a clear answer which is on the one hand solving the question and on the other hand giving advice how to deal with tasks like this in general.